# Seeking MySQL alternative to PostgreSQL ST_SimplifyPolygonHull

Tags: mysql

I need to optimize the timezones GeoJSON from https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder/releases/tag/2022f (timezones-with-oceans.geojson.zip) to be stored in database.

There are some MySQL alternative to PostgreSQL `ST_SimplifyPolygonHull` function?

I have tried also the https://github.com/locationtech/jts package but does not support `FeatureCollection` GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `ST_Simplify(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@GeoJSON, 2, 0), 0.005)`.